# FTP connection through PHP always ask for username & password

Tags: php, ftp

So I have an FTP server with bulk of large files (mostly satellite imagery data). I am building a system with PHP to serve users to download the files. The system can show the list of files in FTP server, so they can download the files. Typically, the list is not from the FTP server, I stored the list in the database.

For FTP connection, I have stored the details (ftp user, ftp password, and ftp server) in a config file. So here I don't want user input anything, just click the download button, and get the files.

The flow of my system is:

1. Check if the requested data is available.
2. If available, then do FTP connection with `ftp_connect`
3. If connection succeed, then login to FTP using `ftp_login`
4. Insert new record to the *log* table in the database.
5. Redirect user to the requested file using PHP header('Location:')
6. Close the FTP connection

It works actually!

But it always asks for FTP username and password for every user download requests.

So what is wrong? Or is there any better approach?

Edit:
Here is the code in download.php:

```
    <?php
    include "config.php";
    include "query_user.php";
    include "function.php"; 

    $data_id = $_GET['data_id'];

    $user_id = $query_user['user_id'];

    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) as jumlah, data_url FROM lord_data WHERE data_id='".$data_id."'");
    $query_data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    if($query_data['jumlah'] > 0){
        $name= $query_data['data_url']; 
        set_time_limit(20);
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 21, 10);
        if($conn_id){
            $conn_login = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
            $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO lord_download_log (user_id, data_id) VALUES ('$user_id', '$data_id')");
            header('Location: ftp://'.$ftp_server.'/foldername/'.$name.'');
            // close the connection
            ftp_close($conn_id);
        }else{
            $ftp_server = "172.xx.xx.xx";
            $change_ip = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 21, 10);
            if($change_ip){
                $conn_login = ftp_login($change_ip, $ftp_user_name,        $ftp_user_pass);
                $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO lord_download_log (user_id, data_id) VALUES ('$user_id', '$data_id')");
                header('Location: ftp://'.$ftp_server.'/foldername/'.$name.'');
                // close the connection
                ftp_close($change_ip);
            }else{  
                echo "Couldn't establish a connection.";
            }
        }

    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Download failed! Data is not available');document.location='index.php?p=data_download';</script>";
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Share your code as well with the question. When you login with `ftp_login`, you should download file with `ftp_get` method

Comment: I have edit the question and paste the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to download file with `ftp_get` method rather than redirecting user to the file location.

Use following code to get file from FTP and force user to download it:

```
$server_file = "/path/to/server/file";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$local_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'download_');
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
  $quoted = sprintf('"%s"', addcslashes(basename($local_file), '"\\'));
  $size   = filesize($local_file);

  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $quoted); 
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: I just got warning:

`Warning: ftp_get(): ftp://172.xx.xx.xx/lisatstor01/LA3_2016-11-08_Muko.zip: No such file or directory`

Comment: Actually, the http and ftp are not in the same server

Comment: @ArifKWijayanto Your path is not correct, maybe try to use path `'/lisatstor01/LA3_2016-11-08_Muko.zip'` only.

Answer (score 0):

@dileep-kumar It works now!

I change the code as follows:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
// connect and login to FTP server
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 21, 10);
$login = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

if($login){
    $chdir = ftp_chdir($conn_id, "lisatstor01");
    $local_file = "local.zip";
    $server_file = "LA3_2016-10-19_Lumajang.zip";

    // download server file
    if (ftp_nb_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY))
      {
          $quoted = sprintf('"%s"', addcslashes(basename($local_file), '"\\'));
          $size   = filesize($local_file);

          header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
          header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $quoted); 
          header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
          header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
          header('Expires: 0');
          header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
          header('Pragma: public');
          header('Content-Length: ' . $size);

        echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Error downloading $server_file.";
    }
}else{
    echo "login failed";
}
// close connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

I change the directory where the files are located. I use `ftp_nb_get` instead of simple `ftp_get`.

The file is downloaded. But it is damaged/corrupted.